# Finding a solution for why background-image won't work?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to use the `background-image` property on a small site I'm making, but to no avail. Here's the code:

```
body {
  background-image: url(/images/Pangolin.png);
  background-size: center;
  font-family: arial, "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

I'm 99% certain the path is correct. I've tried putting the path in quotes, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's developer tools for errors?

Comment: Any guidence on how to do that? From what I can gather, it all seems fine, apart from hovering over the image url yields a "could not load image"

Comment: Press F12 if you're using Chrome or Firefox. Look at the console and network tabs

Comment: Can you try with absolute path? like `background-image: url(http://localhost:8080/images/Pangolin.png);` for example.

Comment: @MaikLowrey that hasn't worked either :(

Comment: @j08691 no errors being thrown up in those places

Comment: @Access547 you got a 404 in you console log? If so, it means that the image path is wrong.

Comment: @MaikLowrey No 404 to be found

Comment: @Access547 Can you open the image if you open the imagelink directly in your browser?

Comment: @MaikLowrey yep :) shows up just fine

Comment: @Access547 Maybe your style.css is not working? can you clear the cache or try to open this site in a new browser?

Comment: @MaikLowrey not working on firefox, chrome or edge. Rest of the page is styled correctly!

Comment: @Access547   Can you put the image path in quotes like: url("/images/Pangolin.png");

Comment: @MaikLowrey hasn't worked either, I had already tried that. I believe you only need quotes if special characters are involved??? Either way no luck there

Comment: @Access547 ok. i can't think of anything else right now either. and your dev tools report something when you look at the body element in the dom?

Comment: @MaikLowrey don't report anything :( Not a problem, I will find another solution, ty for your time!

Comment: @Access547 You can solved?

Comment: Can you tell us the full URL for that image then we can run your CSS for ourselves. Are you for example running this code just on your local machine?

Comment: @Access547 can you post your full CSS and how it is linked to the HTML page? (Embedded in `<style>` or via `<link..` etc.  Is the body tag empty (`<body>`) or does it have IDs or classes attached?

Answer (score -1):

Random shot here but hell, maybe it'll work.

I'm assuming that you're using BEM file structure here.

I think you're just forgetting to go up a level, try putting two periods before the first forward slash if the images folder is in the root level.

So it'd look like;
background-image: url(../images/Pangolin.png);

Comment: @Access547 let me know if this works!

Answer (score -2):

use `cover` for background-size

```
body {
background-image: url( path to image );
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Is that in general or specifically for my issue? Because switching to cover hasn't worked

Comment: maybe your css link is wrong

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.